# didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath returns wrong index

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

my problem is that when i am clicking in the table view it returns this error

```
   2013-02-22 11:22:42.293 Exercise[1570:c07] -[NSIndexPath item]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e7ddd0
```

2013-02-22 11:22:42.294 Exercise[1570:c07] ***

and this is where it returns the wrong index

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  NSLog(@"uitable index: %ld",(long)indexPath.item);

DBHelper *dataObj = [appDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.selIndex = indexPath.item;
LblID = dataObj.dataID;
VCFname.text = dataObj.DBFirstName;
VCLname.text = dataObj.DBLastName;
VCMobile.text = dataObj.DBMobile;
VCEmail.text = dataObj.DBEmail;
VCBday.text = dataObj.DBBirthdate;

NSLog(@"dataID:%i dataArrayCount:%i",self.selIndex,appDelegate.dataArray.count);
```

}

i have connected the table view's delegate and datasource to file owner.

EDIT: additional info
I am trying to get the data from my sqlite database to show on the textfield when i click in the tableview

Comment: Please look at the docs for `NSIndexPath`. There is no `item` property or method. What are you trying to get?

Comment: i am trying to get the data from my database to show on my text fields

Comment: Sorry, I meant what you are trying to get out of the `indexPath` with your attempted use of `item`?

Comment: My apologies. It turns out that `item` is a property of `NSIndexPath` but only as of iOS 6.0. Are you getting this error when run with iOS 5.x?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `NSIndexPath` works. The index path has a 'row' and 'section' property, which you can use to determine the cell tapped. [Here's the documentation for NSIndexPath.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

the `item` property is declared In `UICollectionView.h` not in the  `UITableView.h`. You can see [item](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175). And in the tableView , you should use the `indexPath.section`

Comment: `item` is not part of `UICollectionView`, it is a new property for `NSIndexPath` as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: @rmaddy I do not say item is a part of UICollectionView , a said item is declared in UICollectionView.h , look at my extent link of item

Comment: I was just coming to update my comment. `item` is part of a category for `NSIndexPath` that happens to be declared in `UICollectionView.h`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Although maybe it's technically wrong to use item, item and row both return the second part of the indexPath. You can use either with a tableView in iOS 6, so I don't think that's the problem. It must be which version of iOS he's using.

Comment: @rdelmar Is exactly right.  That is the only way the error message shown would be produced.

Comment: guys thanks for the inpits i have solved this problem by removing this two lines         NSLog(@"uitable index: %ld",(long)indexPath.item);
 self.selIndex = indexPath.item;